# Filter query results by a list of values

Tags: c#, sql, iqueryable

```
 questionnairs = from q in dbContext.AuditQuestionnaires
                                   .Include("Company")
                                where q.Company != null && q.Company.RecordID == companyId
                                select q;
```

im getting some result set using this query, i have set of ids in a integer list, in the questionnaires  result set; there is a id called "recordId", basically I need to  take records which resultSet's record id only if exist in my integer list,

i was trying to do something like this but it failed

```
     for (int x = 0; x < RecordIds.Count; x++)

                    {
                        var id = RecordIds[x];
                        questionnairesList = from q in dbContext.AuditQuestionnaires
                                   .Include("Company")
                                        where q.Company != null && q.Company.RecordID == companyId && q.RecordID == id
                                        select q;

                       


                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Contains

```
questionnairs = from q in dbContext.AuditQuestionnaires
                 .Include("Company")
                  where q.Company != null &&
                        q.Company.RecordID == companyId &&
                        RecordIds.Contains(q.RecordID) 
                  select q;
```